# Relation fields in ArrowDB Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-arrow

Anyone have knowledge about relations and ArrowDB? I'm adding a User object as an relation field to a Message object, and that works fine. But when I try to add an relation to a File object from the same Message object I get the following error:

400: Failed to send message: Invalid ACS type: file

Anyone have a clue?

Maybe I'm using the wrong notation for the File object!? I've tried: [ACS_File], [ACS_Files] without any luck?....[ACS_User] works like a charm?

Here is my code:

```
Cloud.Messages.create({
    to_ids: to.join(','),
    body: 'New Message',
    subject: 'Test Message',
    custom_fields:
    {
    "[ACS_File]file_id":videoFile,
    "[ACS_User]owner_id":to.join(','),

    "pausedAt" : pausedAt,
    "correctAnswer": correctAnswer,
    "a2" : a2,
    "a3" : a3
    }
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        var message = e.messages[0];
        alert('Success:\n' +
            'id: ' + message.id + '\n' +
            'subject: ' + message.subject + '\n' +
            'body: ' + message.body + '\n' +
            'updated_at: ' + message.updated_at);
            //Her gikk alt bra og melding og video er lastet opp. På tide å sende en push :-)


    } else {
        alert('Error:\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
}
```

Comment: What is the value for `videoFile`? An id string or object?

Comment: Hi. The value of videoFile is an id string.

Comment: I think the documentation on relations is somewhat thin: https://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/guide/relationalfields I can't seem to figure out the "fieldname_id" part? in [ACS_<TYPENAME>]<fieldname_id> For what I understand, it should be: [ACS_File]ID_id  if it is the id field of the File object I want refference!?

Comment: The confusing thing is that for example images is refferenced like this: [ACS_Photo]picture_id !? How should I know that the "fieldname" is called "picture" for the Photo object. Where is that documented? Sorry, but it is frustrating. And I've tried all thinkable combinations for the File object without luck...

Comment: As I read it between the square brackets you define the type (`[ACS_File]`) and follow this by the foreign key so to say, which is up to you to define. Perhaps for files it doesn't work. I think it would be best to create a [JIRA](http://jira.appcelerator.org) ticket so this can be fixed as either a doc or code bug.

Comment: Ok I'll create a JIRA ticket. Thank you!

Comment: Have you created the ticket @Janfma ? I just created one now: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-5693